# Elixir + Ecto: Simple WHERE != query

Tags: elixir, ecto

How do you do `WHERE != "something"` in Ecto? I'm using postgres

This is what I have (that doesn't work):

`u = User |> Ecto.Query.where(id: not 444) |> MyApp.Repo.one`

Comment: `|> where([u], u.id != 444)`?

Comment: please give me all your elixir knowledge @Dogbert

Comment: There's a reference of the various boolean operators here: http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/basic-operators.html.  I'm not sure why you didn't try `!=` first yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to use the Ecto Query macros to build this query. For the "expression" based syntax, you can pass a list as the first parameter with the names you'd like to bind the tables with:

```
User |> where([u], u.id != 444)
```

For more info, check out the [documentation of `where`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#where/3).

Comment: given I have the result of `u = User |> where([u], u.id != 444) MyApp.Repo.all`, do you know how I would fetch the first one from that list?

Comment: You can use `|> hd` or do `[u | _] = User |> ...` but if you want only the first result, you should do `where(...) |> limit(1) |> Repo.one`.

Comment: would you by any change know how to do WHERE NOT IN [array]? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41005307/elixir-ecto-how-to-do-where-not-in-array @Dogbert