# Elixir + Ecto: How to do WHERE NOT IN [array]?

Tags: elixir, ecto

I am trying to look for all `User`s that don't have a certain string element in their `match_history` field. I took a guess with this:

`matched_user = User |> where([u], ^device_id not in u.match_history) |> limit(1) |> VideoChat.Repo.one`

But it seems to break at the `not` part. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try

`User |> where([u], not ^device_id in u.match_history)`

Answer (score 1):

For those who are looking for a "array does not contain any" behaviour.
For example *"match_history does not contain device_1 device_2, device_3"*

Given you're using PostgreSQL, can use a fragment with the [array contains `@>` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html).

```
from t in queryable, where: not fragment("? @> ?::varchar[]", t.match_history, ^device_ids)
```

Or

```
from t in queryable, where: fragment("NOT ? @> ?::varchar[]", t.match_history, ^device_ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Elixir 1.7+ you should use:

`User |> where([u], ^device_id not in u.match_history)`.

If you use the accepted answer you will get a compile time warning.